# jQuery File Upload. Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, innerhtml, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I'm trying to use blueimp's jQuery File Upload plugin in my project. This is works perfect in version Basic Plus, i am able to load files on server, but when i am trying to use Basic Plus UI ([link](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/basic-plus.html)) i am getting error:

```
tmpl.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null
    at Function.n.load (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/cp/file_upload/tmpl.min.js:1:324)
    at n (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/cp/file_upload/tmpl.min.js:1:208)
    at n (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/cp/file_upload/tmpl.min.js:1:204)
    at $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._initTemplates (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/cp/file_upload/jquery.fileupload-ui.js:661:46)
    at $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._initTemplates (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/cp/file_upload/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js:127:25)
    at $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._initSpecialOptions (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/cp/file_upload/jquery.fileupload-ui.js:681:18)
    at $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._initSpecialOptions (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/cp/file_upload/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js:127:25)
    at $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._create (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/cp/file_upload/jquery.fileupload.js:1390:18)
    at $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._create (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/cp/file_upload/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js:127:25)
    at $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._super (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/cp/file_upload/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js:114:36)
```

Here is order of js requirements in my project:

```
vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js
JavaScript-Templates/js/tmpl.min.js
JavaScript-Load-Image/js/load-image.all.min.js
canvas-to-blob.min.js
jquery.iframe-transport.js
jquery.fileupload.js
jquery.fileupload-process.js
jquery.fileupload-image.js
jquery.fileupload-validate.js
jquery.fileupload-ui.js
```

Actually, i am getting this error message even if i copy/paste source code from example.

Edit:

here is html code:

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" class="form-control" multiple>
<div id="files" class="files"></div>
```

javascript (copied from blueimp example):

```
$(function () {
    'use strict';

    // Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
        //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
        url: '{% url 'add_request' %}',
    });

    // Enable iframe cross-domain access via redirect option:
    $('#fileupload').fileupload(
        'option',
        'redirect',
        window.location.href.replace(
            /\/[^\/]*$/,
            '/cors/result.html?%s'
        )
    );

    if (window.location.hostname === 'blueimp.github.io') {
        // Demo settings:
        $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', {
            url: '//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/',
            disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
                .test(window.navigator.userAgent),
            maxFileSize: 999000,
            acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i
        });
        // Upload server status check for browsers with CORS support:
        if ($.support.cors) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/',
                type: 'HEAD'
            }).fail(function () {
                $('<div class="alert alert-danger"/>')
                    .text('Upload server currently unavailable - ' +
                            new Date())
                    .appendTo('#fileupload');
            });
        }
    } else {
        // Load existing files:
        $('#fileupload').addClass('fileupload-processing');
        $.ajax({
            // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
            //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
            url: $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', 'url'),
            dataType: 'json',
            context: $('#fileupload')[0]
        }).always(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('fileupload-processing');
        }).done(function (result) {
            $(this).fileupload('option', 'done')
                .call(this, $.Event('done'), {result: result});
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: Post relevant code you are using in question itself

Comment: @a-wolff Just edited my post

Comment: @umaru Where you have used 'innerHTML' ?

Comment: @nitin-dhomse this is from JavaScript-Templates/js/tmpl.min.js https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Templates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. Problem was not in javascript. I use django tags in template. So I had to put JavaScript-Templates tags into {% verbatim %} django tag.
Thanx everyone.